# メンテナンスのお知らせ：2月1日 (木) 10:00 〜 JST

Tags: 討議

メンテナンス作業が無事終了しました。

---

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396304/314875) に記載されている通り、日本時間の 2024 年 2 月 1 日 (木) 午前 10 時頃から、約 1 時間のメンテナンスが予定されています。この期間中、メンテナンスが始まる前にログインしている場合、Stack Overflow サイトと Stack Exchange サイトは通常通り機能しますが、**ログインしていない場合**、メンテナンスが終了するまでログインできません。その他のサイトの機能 (チャットなど) には影響がありません。メンテナンスが終了し、ユーザーがログインできるようになると、この投稿を更新いたします。ご不便をおかけしますが、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。